# Im trying to get a text from a tkinter entry and put it inside a dictionary but I get PY_VAR(some number) instead

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

the code below is part of a class.

```
def expected_callback(self,expected_val_var,index,mode):
      dictionary[self.row][3] = expected_val_var
def dataType callback(self,event):
    expected_val_var = StringVar()
    expected_val_var.trace("w",self.expected_callback)
    expected_val = Entry(self.root, width=20, textvariable= expected_val_var)
    expected_val.insert(0,"Expected value")
    expected_val.grid(row=self.row,column=self.col+2)
```

Im trying to get a text from a tkinter entry and put it inside a dictionary but I get PY_VAR(some number) instead.

I also tried `dictionary[self.row][3] = expected_val_var.widget.get()` but it said that str has no get(). What can I do to get the users input from expected_val entry into the dictionary?

Comment: You should just simply use `get()`, not `widget.get()`. `dictionary[self.row][3] = expected_val_var.get()`

Comment: I tried it but it says that str has no attribute get. For some reason the expected_val_var is a 'PY_VAR1' string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the first argument of the callback for `.trace()` is the internal name (string) of the tkinter variable.

If you want to pass `expected_val_var` (instance of `StringVar`) to `expected_callback()`, use lambda on `.trace()` instead:

```py
def expected_callback(self, expected_val_var):
    dictionary[self.row][3] = expected_val_var.get()

def dataType_callback(self, event):
    ...
    expected_val_var.trace("w", lambda *args: self.expected_callback(expected_val_var)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure, shouldn't it be

dictionary[self.row][3] = expected_val.get()

but I would rename

> expected_val

to something like

> entry_field

for to be clearer that it is the input
element which value is to be red

and are you sure about

> deff

, I know it as

> def

Comment: deff was a typo and when I use expected_val.get() I get a 'str' object has no attribute 'get'